# Accidentally pushed button in sublime and now I got highlighted code, even on restart

Tags: sublimetext3

After hitting something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>  I "highlighted" open and closed tags, but even on restart this won't go away, it's very odd and happens very often so I'm not sure what's up with that.

I use Sublime Text 3 with Predawn theme, here is an example.

[image]

Comment: I can't see any menu options that would highlight tags (although I don't use tagged files often so may be missing something). Do you have any additional plugins installed that may be causing this? Possibly something like BracketHighligher -https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter

Comment: Yep, that was it! But I'm not sure what caused it to highlight a tag even after Sublime restart?